# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP and I've encountered a small problem. When I run the script without variables it displays `success=false`, but when I add username and pass from the database - it displays `success=true`.

Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement on line 8, and then it fetches the values from the database. My question is, what am I doing wrong and where is the problem?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in", "test", "test", "test");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $name, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $name, $password, $email, $phonenumber);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["phonenumber"] = $phonenumber;

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You should not be storing _plain text passwords_ on your database. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them, I might want to use your site one day
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You should not be running this code if the `$_POST['name'] and $_POST['password']` do not exist. Check they exist before running this code

Comment: RiggsFolly my question is how can I fix the error? And the php is for an inhouse project so no fear of losing passwords

Comment: That is how you can fix the error!!

Comment: **NOTE:** Most system hacks are perpetrated or assisted by **IN HOUSE STAFF** So that is not an excuse for sloppy/lazy/insecure coding

Comment: I suggest that you do not use `select * ` when binding explicit result variables. If the table get ts a new column then your script fails. i.e. lit the columns in the `select` query.

Comment: I removed the $name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];, but the result is the same